# Angular4 module scopes not working

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular, been using AngularJs for some time though. I decided to make the transition to Angular and have been following [the style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide).

I have set up my modules like this (I have no shown my components for brevity, but they should be self explanatory)

> /app.module.ts
>
> /core/core.module.ts
>
> /data/data.module.ts
>
> /directives/directives.module.ts
>
> /home/home.module.ts
>
> /results/results.module.ts

So basically, I use the **core** module to handle all other modules. It looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { DataModule } from '../data/data.module';
import { DirectivesModule } from '../directives/directives.module';
import { HomeModule } from '../home/home.module';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { QuestionModule } from '../question/question.module';
import { ResultsModule } from '../results/results.module';

import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { ResultsComponent } from '../results/results.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DataModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    SharedModule,

    HomeModule,
    QuestionModule,
    ResultsModule,

    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'results', component: ResultsComponent },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path:'', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

and in my **app** module, I have tried to keep it small, so it just looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent   
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The problem is, when I run my site I get errors stating that the **question** component can't be found.
Also, it moans about my directives not being found either.

I thought that declaring the components/directives in their respective module and importing all them modules into the core module which is then imported into the app module would allow all components access to directives, etc.

The app component uses a data service and that works fine, so I just dont understand why the others are failing.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The modules in your CoreModule should be in the AppModule. As you've read in the style docs, you mainly use the CoreModule to add providers that should have singleton instance. Let me know if you still need clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to `export` component out of your module. i.e. in module definvation you have have to provide one more array of export

```
exports:[coponent want to export]
```

so in questionmodule you have to write this.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [QustionComponent, other component],
  imports: [module toimport ],
  providers: [service provider],
  exports:[QuestionComponent, other coponent you want to export ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you have to export the components you ca re-use.

Directives, component, and pipes for instance, are components you can re-use.

If you want it to work, simply add an `exports` property in your concerned modules (being CoreModule and DirectivesModule), that will contain your QuestionComponent, all of you directives.

(keep in mind that you need to **export imported components**; this means you have to import it first, in the same module)

Comment: Am I wrong, but you can't import a component/directive? Do you mean you have to add it to declarations first?

Comment: No you're right, I have been writing too fast. You need to declare it, not import it ! Imports are for modules, my bad.